# Pregunta: Crear sentencias SQL a partir de un txt plano (C#)

Tags: c#, .net

Buenas tardes, estoy intentando crear un pequeño programa para convertir texto plano (.txt) en otro documento con las sentencias SQL (insert), normalmente suelo ocuparme de otras funcionalidades o proyectos y me ha pillado con la guardia un poco baja, ¿alguien tiene una documentación de como serializar un dato plano en txt para crear INSERTS dinámicos a partir de la información que se da?

ejemplo:

**1manual 004


2automatico 001 34533 2345


1manual 005


1manual 007


2automático 002 45644 3456**

la idea sería distinguir entre manual y automático y crear un insert distinto para cada cual.

PD: no deseo una solucion (si es sencilla no me importaría), pero sobre todo busco documentación y formas de ejecutar este pequeño programa :)

gracias.

Comment: Lo que comentas es bastante sencillo, siempre y cuando el formato sea siempre igual. Primero tendrias que leer el archivo de texto, posteriormente ir leyendo linea a linea y separando los campos mediante `Split` y finalmente,dependiendo del primer campo, componer una sentencia sql u otra

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bueno, como es algo sencillo te pongo un codigo de ejemplo. En este código se lee un archivo de entrada de ejemplo con los datos que tu nos has dado, y se escriben las sentencias en otro archivo. Sería algo asi:

```
string[] filas=File.ReadAllLines("c:\\temp\\sentencias.txt");
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("c:\\temp\\sentencias.sql");
foreach (string fila in filas)
{
     string sql = "INSERT ";
     string[] campos = fila.Split(' ');

     if (campos[0]== "1manual")
     {
          //Insert de tipo manual
          sql+= " INTO TABLA1 (CAMPO1) VALUES (" + campos[1] +");";
     }
     else
     {
          //insert de tipo automatico
          sql += " INTO TABLA2 (CAMPO1,CAMPO2,CAMPO3) VALUES (" + campos[1] + "," + campos[2] + "," + campos[3] + ");";
     }
     sw.WriteLine(sql);
}

sw.Close();
```

Esto genera en la salida un archivo similar a esto:

```
INSERT  INTO TABLA1 (CAMPO1) VALUES (004);
INSERT  INTO TABLA2 (CAMPO1,CAMPO2,CAMPO3) VALUES (001,34533,2345);
INSERT  INTO TABLA1 (CAMPO1) VALUES (005);
INSERT  INTO TABLA1 (CAMPO1) VALUES (007);
INSERT  INTO TABLA2 (CAMPO1,CAMPO2,CAMPO3) VALUES (002,45644,3456);
```

Comment: y si por ejemplo el principio de cada campo fuera siempre "01cosa" o "01algomas" como haría para solo tener en cuenta el "01"?

Comment: En ese caso tendrias que obtener los datos de los dos primeros caracteres, algo asi como `fila.Substring(0, 2);`,siempre y cuando siempre fueran dos caracteres los que hay que tomar en cuenta. Si no, la cosa empezaria a complicarse ;)

Comment: me comenta que no se puede convertir implicitamente 'string' a 'string[]', Lo que hice fué mas o menos: string campos = fila.Substring(0, 2);

                        if (campos.Contains("1m"))

Comment: Claro. `Substring` devuelve un `string`,mientras que `Split` devuelve un array. Todo depende de cuales sean tus datos de entrada reales para usar uno u otro, o cualquier combinacion de ellos.

Answer (score 1):

Finalmente con la ayuda de Pikoh he conseguido dar con la solución:

```
string mydate = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
                    string AÑO = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy");
                    string MES = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM");
                    string DIA = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd");
                    string sql = "INSERT ";
                    string[] campos = fila.Split(' ');

                    if (campos[0].StartsWith("1H"))
                    {

                        sql += "INTO TABLE (VALUES,VALUES,VALUES) VALUES (" + "'" + mydate + "'" + "," + "'" + campos[0].Substring(1, 8) + "'" + "," + "'" + campos[0].Substring(9, 7) + "'" + "," + "'" + campos[8] + "'" + ");";
```

insertar datos, fechas y manipular cadenas de texto me ha enseñado mucho, pero ahora tengo otro problema:

**Si deseo aplicar un "retroceso" a una cadena especifica, como podría hacerlo? (osea se un backspace a un string específico).**

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Un punto importante que noto es como procesar los datos del archivo, aconsejaria evalues usar

[filehelpers](http://www.filehelpers.net/)

con este podrias mapear por un ancho fijo o por algun separador cada valor de las lineas y convertir esto a una lista de una clase que definas

Esto te permite tener cada dato del archivo para generar las queries, solo sera cuestion de recorrer cada entidad en la lista parseada y generar el INSERT en un string